# Web API 2 redirect from GetExternalLogin

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to get my head around the new setup for Web API 2 with Identity and external authentication providers. My scenario - two asp.net applications, Web API as data provider and MVC as data consumer. I call GetExternalLogins method in Web API and based on returned list generate series of links in my MVC application. Whenever user clicks any of them she is redirected to GetExternalLogin method:

```
    // GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ExternalLogin", Name = "ExternalLogin")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExternalLogin(string provider, string sender, string error = null)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Content("~/") + "#error=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(error));
        }

        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        if (externalLogin == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (externalLogin.LoginProvider != provider)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, this);
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            externalLogin.ProviderKey));

        bool hasRegistered = user != null;

        if (hasRegistered)
        {
            Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookieIdentity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = ApplicationOAuthProvider.CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            Authentication.SignIn(properties, oAuthIdentity, cookieIdentity);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = externalLogin.GetClaims();
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            Authentication.SignIn(identity);
        }

        var test = Ok();

        return Ok();
    }
```

And everything works fine. I do manage to login (I use Google for testing purposes) but am redirected to Web API while I would like to return back to my MVC application. I do pass the return string as "sender" parameter but don't know how to approach the response url to parse the access_token value out of it?

Comment: Not sure if this tutorial addresses EXACTLY what you're wondering, however I found it to have some useful insights on the External Login workflow, so it would prolly be worth a look regardless: http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/26/dissecting-the-web-api-individual-accounts-templatepart-3-external-accounts/